# Calling multiple functions after clicking Submit button

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and python, I have various functions made in python which i want to run after clicking the submit button  (obviously getting inputs from the form) and then show the results on similar page or maybe new page.

A proper guidance and a pseudo code would help me achieve this.

Thank you.

python code snippet:

```
def func1():
     .....
func1()

def func2():
     .....
func2()
```

Django form:

```
enter URL : 
Submit
```

now after someone click submit i want to display results of func1 and func2 together.

Comment: Please explain how are you currently trying to solve the problem. A code snippet would be good. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AdityaAgrawal Done, please check now

Comment: It would've been great if you could've provided some code you wrote to implement your solution. Nevertheless, check my answer below for an approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can create another function and in that, call all the other functions that you want.
for example:

```
def func():
   func1()
   func2()
   func3()
   func4()
```

then you can just call func() in your code! in this way you can easily call multiple functions and put them in same category

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a form called MyForm and functions func1() and func2() that return some value, you can try something like the following.

```py
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import MyForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            myContext={}
            myContext['res1']=func1() #Your custom functions
            myContext['res2']=func2() #Pass any arguments needed by the function
            return render(None, template='yourResultPage.html', context=myContext)


    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'formpage.html', {'form': form})
```

Please note that using render after form submit is not recommended and you should prefer redirecting and using the message framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something akin, but your question is ambiguous and ought to be much more specific.

```
   def called_on_sumbit(request):   
     if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                callme()

        def function1():
            return x
        def function 2():
            return y

         def callme():
            answer1 = function1()
            answer2 = function2()
                return
```